"WebDriverException: Message: Service unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 64" with Selenium 4.21, Firefox 127 and GeckoDriver 0.34
I have a portable installation of Firefox 127 alongside GeckoDriver 0.34, and the following code on Selenium 4.21 (Python 3.11.7).
C:\Users\myuser\Portables\Geckodriver is in my local path environment.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

service_binary = r"C:\Users\myuser\Portables\Geckodriver\geckodriver-v0.34.0-win64.exe"
browser_binary = r"C:\Users\myuser\Portables\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

service = Service(service_binary, log_path="geckodriver.log", service_args=["--verbose"])

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.binary_location = browser_binary

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)

When I run it I get the following error, with both GeckoDriver x64 and x32. The geckodriver.log file doesn't get generated either as I can't find it anywhere.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 14
     11 options.add_argument('--headless')
     12 options.binary_location = browser_binary
---> 14 driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)

File c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py:62, in WebDriver.__init__(self, options, service, keep_alive)
     59     options.browser_version = None
     61 self.service.path = finder.get_driver_path()
---> 62 self.service.start()
     64 executor = FirefoxRemoteConnection(
     65     remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     66     keep_alive=keep_alive,
     67     ignore_proxy=options._ignore_local_proxy,
     68 )
     70 try:

File c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py:102, in Service.start(self)
    100 count = 0
    101 while True:
--> 102     self.assert_process_still_running()
    103     if self.is_connectable():
    104         break

File c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py:115, in Service.assert_process_still_running(self)
    113 return_code = self.process.poll()
    114 if return_code:
--> 115     raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")

WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Users\myuser\Portables\Geckodriver\geckodriver-v0.34.0-win64.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 64

Any idea on what's wrong with it? I'm pretty sure GeckoDriver 0.34 is compatible with Firefox 127 as per https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html
